# No database selected error in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to connect to a local database and execute a query:

```
        $dbost="localhost";
        $dbuser="root";
        $dbpass="";
        $dbname="schoolspace_push";
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbost", $dbuser, $dbpass);   
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_project WHERE project_title=:project_title";

        $project_title = 'beaufort';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("project_title", $project_title);
        $stmt->execute();
        $project = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

Only to get the error:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'
```

What could be causing this? I 100% have a database in phpmyadmin called "schoolspace_push" and the user is "root" with no password...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

You were not passing in a database name.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't telling PDO which database to use.

You can either add `dbname=$dbname` to your dsn.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

or run this directly after connecting

```
$db->query("use $dbname;");
```

Answer (score 1):

castis and Nicholas Young are both correct. However you can also specify the database within the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbname.tbl_project WHERE project_title=:project_title";
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
try 
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname', 'dbuser' , 'password');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXECPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAME "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error= 'error text';
  include 'errorpage.php';
  exit();
}

$success = 'success';
include 'page.php';
```